# Is there a way in MySQL to forbid unindexed queries?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'd like to prevent any query that does not use a Primary Key or an already existing index.
Is there a way to enforce this on the sessions or server level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Not so long answer: You may use the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html) to at least catch "slow" queries and create the necessary indexes.

Longer answer: The usage of indexes is mainly up to the query planner. So, there might be situations in which there is a candidate index, but the engine prefers to discard it. So, it is somewhat chaotic for solid restrictions like the one you want.

Comment: My goal is really to forbid those, to prevent our devs to do queries in ways that we do not want. We want it to fail fast so they know they are doing something wrong.

Comment: The only way I see to achieve something similar to your goal is to deny access privileges to tables, and provide stored procedures written specifically with queries tuned to use the indexes. That is a burden, and probably a shift in development policies. From what  I see in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html) MySQL doesn't provide what you need at session / server level. Hope you find a way!